# What is the equivalent of 'sources' in gradle-scoverage in version 7, in the latest gradle-scoverage version 8

Tags: scala, gradle, scoverage, gradle-scoverage

In gradle-scoverage version 7.0.3
I have

```
scoverage {
     sources = file("{sourceDir}")
```

I have upgraded to gradle-scoverage version 8.0.3
it says that sources does not exists any more.
What is its equivalent ?